# Avoid trigger again _SelectionChanged when I set SelectedItem to null

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 and I have a single selection Listbox and this method:

```
private void locationsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ARLocation item = (ARLocation)locationsList.SelectedItem;

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/MapPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    locationsList.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

When I do `locationsList.SelectedItem = null;` the `SelectionChanged` event is triggered again.

**How can I avoid that the event is triggered when I clear SelectedItem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you don't want to unsubscribe from the event, you cannot avoid it - you are changing selected item, so it is firing the event.

You can try to do such a thing - unsubscribe and then subscribe to the event:

```
locationsList.SelectioChanged -= locationsList_SelectionChanged;
locationsList.SelectedItem = null;
locationsList.SelectioChanged += locationsList_SelectionChanged;
```

But it may be easier in this case to perform a check-up:

```
private void locationsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem != null)
  {
    ARLocation item = (ARLocation)locationsList.SelectedItem;

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/MapPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    locationsList.SelectedItem = null;
  }
}
```

Or you may provide a boolean to inform the event that it should be skipped:

```
private bool SkipEvent = false;

private void locationsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (SkipEvent) return;
  ARLocation item = (ARLocation)locationsList.SelectedItem;

  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/MapPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

  // Skip block:
  try
  {
    SkipEvent = true;
    locationsList.SelectedItem = null;
  }
  finally { SkipEvent = false; }
}
```